# File.Exist always return false

Tags: c#

I know it's been asked a lot already, but I still can't get my code to work.

I built a little programm which lets you choose a product and asks for your information if you want to buy it. Every time the given information like name, address and so on... is saved in a single Excel file.

Now I want this file to be created if it doesn't already exists. It works to create one, and overwrite it. But if it exists, `File.Exist` will return a false anyway and overwrite the entire file with a new blank. It get's created to `[user]\Documents` folder.

My idea to check if the file already exists was this:

```
if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Bestellungen.xlsx"))
{
    CreateNewHistory(); // Method which creates the file in correct format
}
WriteData(); // Method to write given information to correct cells
```

The method for creating the file is simply:

```
private void CreateNewHistory()
{
    Excel excel = new Excel();

    excel.CreateNewFile();
    excel.SaveAs(@"Bestellungen.xlsx");
    ...
    // some cells get writte here, just for format
    ...
    excel.Close();
}
```

"Bestellungen" is German for "orders"... ;)

I suppose it has something to do with the way I pass the path into `File.Exist` but I am just clueless. I tried to copy the file into the bin\debug folder of my project. If it's there it works perfectly, but i really would like to know how i can find the file in the documents folder. I already tried put the absolute path, but it's always returning false.

If you need more information about the code let me know, I'm really new to c# or coding basically.

Comment: You used a *relative* path to save the file. The file is stored in your application's working directory, not `C:\`. In fact, you can't save anything to a disk's root folder without elevated permissions

Comment: You are searching the file in the root od the system drive. This place is usually protected by the OS, so the error could be simply that you don't have permission there. However, you create the file in the current folder (no path given) so unless the current folder is the root of the system drive you are checking a folder and creating the file in another folder

Comment: You can access Document folder using - Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

Comment: You are searching for file in C drive and creating file in application folder. That's why this magic is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're saving the file using a *relative* path. The file will be saved in the program's working directory. Using `C:\` will never work. In fact, you can't even write to the root folder without elevated privileges. `Program Files` is another folder you can't (and shouldn't even try) to save into, since 1995.

Older Windows versions would just throw an exception. Some developers would try to force permissions instead of fix their bugs, so newer versions redirect inappropriate writes to eg `Documents` or `APPDATA`. I suspect you run your program from `Program Files` and the OS redirected the file save operation to `Documents`.

You should use an absolute path to save files in the correct folder. User documents go to `Documents`, application files go to `APPDATA` etc. You can get the absolute path to each of those locations with [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.8), and one of the [SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) values like `Desktop` or `MyDocuments` eg :

```
var docFolder=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var filePath=Path.Combine(docFolder,"Bestellungen.xlsx");
excel.SaveAs(filePath);
```

And retrieve it the same way:

```
var docFolder=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var filePath=Path.Combine(docFolder,"Bestellungen.xlsx");
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
...
```

The `SpecialFolder` enumeration explains the purpose of the various folders:

- `MyDocuments` contains document files for the current user,
- `Desktop` points to the current user's desktop
- `ApplicationData` and `LocalApplicatinoData` contain application-specific files used by the current user,  like logs and settings etc.
- `CommonDocuments`, `CommonDesktop`, `CommonApplicationData`contain files used by *all* users on a computer

Comment: Oh man it's finally working! thank you so much. I knew there was some issue with the path, just couldn't figure it out. Learned a lot from you answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Document folder to save your file.

1. Get the User Document Folder

   ```
   String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
   ```
2. Set the Filename

   ```
   string file="Bestellungen.xlsx";
   ```
3. Finally, generate your actual path

   ```
   String absolutePath  = System.IO.Path.Combine(path , file);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

its throw a exception due to permission issue 
please change directory or give proper permission